# Pandas pd.concat or R rbind - Error after merging

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames df1 and df2 with the same data types and the same column names.

now when I extract df1 from the merged frame and compare it with the original data frame I have an error!! I mean it shows they are not equal??

I don't understand why is there an error after concatenating two data frames even if they have same datatypes and data formats.

I checked the same using **rbind** in Rstudio and I still get errors like

please let me know if you ever faced a problem like this or any suggestions for a solution

---

**Dummy Data Example (Since the data I have is confidential):**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"age_grp": ["<30", "30-40", "50-60", ">70"],
                   "year": [2015, 2015, 2015, 2015],
                   "sex": ["Male", "Female", "Female", "Male"],
                   "country": ["UK","France","Portugal","USA"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"age_grp": ["30-40", "50-60","<30", ">70"],
                   "year": [2016, 2016, 2016, 2016],
                   "sex": ["Male", "Female", "Female", "Male"],
                   "country": ["France","France","USA","USA"]})

#concat two dfs
new_df = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)

#extract year 2016 from the merged dataframe(new_df)
extract = new_df.loc[new_df['year'] == 2016]

#compare extract with the original df2
extract.equals(df2) # should return TRUE but I am getting "False" with the data I have
```

**Code used in R:**

```
all.equal(extract,df2) #for comparison

The error I got:
[1] "Component “age_grp”: Attributes: < Component “levels”: Lengths (7, 6) differ (string compare on first 6) >"                
 [2] "Component “name”: Attributes: < Component “levels”: Lengths (120, 103) differ (string compare on first 103) >"               
 [3] "Component “setting”: Attributes: < Component “levels”: Lengths (17, 13) differ (string compare on first 13) >"                
 [4] "Component “sex”: Attributes: < Component “levels”: Lengths (8, 7) differ (string compare on first 7) >"
```

Comment: Because you have not done it correctly. We cannot provide help unless you provide the data for us to reproduce the issue

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is highly sensitive and confidential. I am not allowed to share the data. So, I am asking a generalized question.

Comment: You can create a dummy data. We just have to get the idea of how the data looks like and try reproduce the same error/issue on our end. Create the dummy data of df1 and df2 and share those one

Comment: I created dummy data for your reference. Please let me know if you have any leads.

Comment: The issue is regarding the index. When you extract, you get the index from the combined. reset and drop the index. ie `extract = new_df.loc[new_df['year'] == 2016].reset_index(drop = True)` now compare